# Can you please help me to display the correct grand total in crystal reports

Tags: crystal-reports

my grand total in crystal reports is coming up in thousands instead of hundred eg i've got a column of amount for  products etc the amounts are:
10.00
42.00
55.00
45.00
75.00

it adds up to 227.00 but in the report the grand total is showing 22,700.00....please help!!!

Comment: Try right-clicking the total and looking at the summary (Edit Summary) and/or number format (Format Field).  Something is automatically re-formatting it for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

The most likely culprit for an unexpected grand total is incorrect grouping.  If you don't have totals on each group, add them, and see if those are off.  Once you fix the grouping, and making sure you're totalling on the correct field, then your grand totals should also be correct.